# Groovy / Grails using a map as a parameter of a function

Tags: grails

I have a very simple function which I define as follows:

```
 def mySimpleFunction(Map myMap) {
   // Function logic here...
  }
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get a warning message and build exception which says that:  The [mySimpleFunction] action accepts a parameter of type [java.util.Map] which has not been marked with Validateable.

How can I mark this function as Validateable? I imported the **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.Validateable**

and have marked my class as @Validateable .

What should I be doing differently in order to get my application to build?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is this function?  A controller, service, etc?

Comment: Mark the method as @Validatable.  I'm unsure of the reason for this beyond the magic map / params binding that grails does in controllers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it is a helper method, make it private. In Grails 2.0+ public controller methods are assumed to be actions, and arguments are assumed to be bindable. That means they need to be number types, boolean, String, etc., or a command object class.

Command object classes are automatically made validateable if they're defined in the controller class file, and if they're defined elsewhere they need to be annotated as `@Validateable`.

Since this is a helper method and not an action, just make it private (especially since it can't be called from another class anyway):

```
private mySimpleFunction(Map myMap) {
   // Function logic here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Burt! Appreciate it. Looking forward to reading your new book once it's available too.