# Grails warning at compile of controllers

Tags: grails

I am currently getting the warning in Grails of

'The [update] action accepts a parameter of type [edu.acu.teachereval.SubjectCode] which has not been marked with @Validateable.  Data binding will still be applied to this command object but the instance will not be validateable.
       @Transactional'

along with the same errors for show, save, edit, and delete for the controller mentioned in the error and other controllers that I have created. I have seen this issue for user created functions, but I have not seen this error for functions that are built in to grails. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add a `@Validateable` annotation to your `SubjectCode` class.

[Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationNonDomainAndCommandObjectClasses)

Comment: Adding that to the domain class fixed the warning. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This may be coming late, But this error is likely to occur when you use models not created in the domain conventional folder.

It seems grails automatically injects the `@Validateable` annotation to domain classes/models in the `domain` Folder,

If you therefore create your models in the src/grails or src/java folder, You are likely to get this error when the model object is passed/posted/submited via a View to a controller function.

1. Try adding the `@Validateable` annotation to the domain object
2. Move the domain model to the domain grails convention folder

Answer (score 1):

or maybe Grails is overreaching while simultaneously giving misleading error messages... nah, that never happens.  For a more relevant answer, see:

[Groovy / Grails using a map as a parameter of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350684/groovy-grails-using-a-map-as-a-parameter-of-a-function)